# What's the relationship between template engine, data binding? When to use which?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, reactjs, template-engine

Recently I run across the concept of template engine.

If I'm using `angular or react`, both frameworks provides some kind of data binding function by using the syntax: `{{ xxx }}`.

1. Does it mean the modern `javascript` framework obsolete the usage of template engine?
2. Or the fact that data binding can work is all because those frameworks have included their own template engine implementation, after all, it's still some template engine working behind the scene?
3. when to use a dedicated template engine like: `handlebars, ejs, mustache`?
4. what's the difference between client side template engine and server side template engine ??

Comment: Your question heading is not  in sync with actual content, it seems.

Comment: short answer on template engines is that is part of a framework and why the term isn't used as much any more

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to understand the requirement of Template Engine, Data Binding, Client side Data Binding and then discuss your questions.

1) A template engine (also known as a template processor or template parser) is software designed to combine one or more templates with a data model to produce one or more result documents. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor).

2)Template engines are tools to separate program-logic and presentation into two independent parts.This makes the development of both logic and presentation easier, improves flexibility and eases modification and maintenance.[Source](http://www.simple-is-better.org/template/#id2).

With the above discussion, we understand that **data binding is the task accomplished by a template engine**.

Now comes to your questions:

Yes, Angular is a complete UI rendering client framework. You can feed data into it, and it will render the proper html. On it's own Angular is a templating solution completely de-coupled from any server.

Now a days, client side templating is much popular. But we need to understand the issues and benefits of client side templating.

1) By client side templating we can save a lot of CPU time, waste in data binding. And let such use less task on client browser where most of cases 99% CPU is in ideal state. That means improved response time.

2) A user surfs to your Angular site. Let’s say he uses a mobile browser, since that’s the more tricky use case. Let’s go through everything that happens in this user’s browser.

The browser downloads the HTML, CSS, images, Angular, and site-specific scripts. After the downloading Angular itself must be initialised, i.e. the browser has to go through the framework and start up all JavaScript objects and what not that the framework is going to need later on, when it comes to actually binding data and behaviour to HTML elements.

This step can take some time, especially on mobile browsers, which have slower processors and less memory than desktop browsers.

In such case we may losing our loyal userbase.

To choose client side template engine or server side template engine is all about the requirement and target users. What kind of facility they have and what best you want to provide them. What's the capability of servers you hold.

Comment: You were doing great up until the point of *"In such case we may losing our loyal userbase."* . You make it sound like there is always a huge amount of time on initial page load. That sure goes against common trends of how many apps are being developed as SPA these days